# Switch section and subsection in beamer head (infolines)

Tags: beamer

An example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{lmodern}

\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty %remove navigation panel

%Some colors
\definecolor{generalcolor}{gray}{0.3}
\definecolor{accent1}{RGB}{0, 110, 220} %blue
\definecolor{accent2}{RGB}{255, 248, 220} %cornsilk 
\definecolor{accent3}{RGB}{255, 228, 181} %moccasin

\useoutertheme{infolines} %adds bottom bar with info
\setbeamercolor{palette primary}{fg=accent3,bg=accent1} %date
\setbeamercolor{palette secondary}{fg=accent1,bg=accent2} %title
\setbeamercolor{palette tertiary}{fg=accent2,bg=accent3} %name+institute

\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=accent1,bg=accent2} 

\begin{document}



\section{Introduction}
\subsection{Emulsions}
\begin{frame}
 \frametitle{Emulsions}

 hello


 \note{what I should say}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

creates a header like this:
[image: example]

Goals:

- I want the section content to go into the right header bar
- I want the subsection content to go into the left header bar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could redefine the template.

[image: header]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{lmodern}

\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty %remove navigation panel

%Some colors
\definecolor{generalcolor}{gray}{0.3}
\definecolor{accent1}{RGB}{0, 110, 220} %blue
\definecolor{accent2}{RGB}{255, 248, 220} %cornsilk 
\definecolor{accent3}{RGB}{255, 228, 181} %moccasin

\useoutertheme{infolines} %adds bottom bar with info
\setbeamercolor{palette primary}{fg=accent3,bg=accent1} %date
\setbeamercolor{palette secondary}{fg=accent1,bg=accent2} %title
\setbeamercolor{palette tertiary}{fg=accent2,bg=accent3} %name+institute

\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=accent1,bg=accent2}

\setbeamertemplate{headline}{
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.65ex,dp=1.5ex,right]{subsection in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{subsection in head/foot}\insertsubsectionhead\hspace*{2ex}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.65ex,dp=1.5ex,left]{section in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{section in head/foot}\hspace*{2ex}\insertsectionhead
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}

\begin{document}



\section{Introduction}
\subsection{Emulsions}
\begin{frame}
 \frametitle{Emulsions}

 hello


 \note{what I should say}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```